# Referencing Serverless Output returns "[object Object]" instead of arn

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless-framework-step-functions

I'm using State Machines for the first time, and I'm having trouble referencing the State Machine arn in my Lambda function. I've tried following this [article](https://medium.com/@iamNoah_/referencing-lambda-or-step-functions-using-the-serverless-framework-9af60f3097d6) and the [docs](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-step-functions#how-to-specify-the-statemachine-arn-to-environment-variables), but I must be missing something, because instead of the arn, I'm getting "[object Object]".

Environment Variable:

```
  environment:
    EMAIL_STATE_MACHINE: ${self:resources.Outputs.EmailQueueStateMachine.Value}
```

Output:

```
  Outputs:
    EmailQueueStateMachine:
      Description: The ARN of the email delivery state machine
      Value:
        Ref: EmailQueueStateMachine
```

State Machine:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    ReportDeliveryEmailQueueStateMachine:
      name: emailQueueStateMachine
      id: EmailQueueStateMachine
      dependsOn:
        - EmailTemplatesDynamoDbTable
      definition:
       <definition>
```

Everything I've read has this same setup, so I know I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Here is a related issue https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5209
I had to hardcode the arn in my custom serverless variables.

Comment: Thanks for the link - yes, I ended up needing to hardcode as well.